# Getting time from date range interval text column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that is in the format of

```
2/23/23 9:00 am - 2/23/23 9:59 am
```

I am using a select statement to get the start date and start time from this column as follows:

```
start date: LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX(' ',[Date]) + 0))))))
start time: RTRIM(LTRIM(FORMAT(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(RIGHT(RIGHT(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1), LEN(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1)) - PATINDEX( '%/[12][0-9] %',LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1))),LEN(RIGHT(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1), LEN(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1)) - PATINDEX( '%/[12][0-9] %',LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1)))) - 1))),'am','AM'),'pm','PM') AS datetime),'hh:mm tt')))

Desired output for time: 9:00 am
```

The start date works but for start time I am having issues now when the year is formatted as /2023 instead of /23 because I will have both of these year formats included in my table.

What I tried is adding another % to account for the 2 extra digits in the year as follows:

```
PATINDEX( '%/%[12][0-9] %'
```

but this gives me 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' error.

What should I change in my start time select statement to account for having both '2023' and '23' in the year part.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get time difference between two dates, you can use something like this:

```
;WITH InitialData(TimeRange) AS
(
  SELECT '2/23/23 9:00 am - 2/23/23 9:59 am'
),
CTE( StartDate, EndDate ) AS
(
  SELECT CAST(LEFT(TimeRange, CHARINDEX('-', TimeRange)-2) AS DATETIME2), 
    CAST(RIGHT(TimeRange,LEN(TimeRange)-CHARINDEX('-', TimeRange)-1) AS DATETIME2)
  FROM InitialData
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(MI, StartDate, EndDate) AS TimeDiff
FROM CTE;
```

Working example here: [DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zLib7mqB)

Answer (score 1):

Getting the date and time from a string, just parse out the portion you require and then assuming your dates are consisent, 2 or 4 digit years are both valid, so use cast/convert - something like:

```
with munged as (
  select dt = '2/23/23 9:00 am - 2/23/23 9:59 am' union all 
  select dt = '2/23/2023 9:00 am - 2/23/2023 9:59 am'
)
select Convert(date, d.d), Convert(time, d.d)
from munged
cross apply(values( Left(dt, CharIndex('-', dt) -1) ))d(d)
```